# Question about the problem of interfacing BLDC motor with L9110 , STM32 and DHT11 for temperature based speed control

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, arm

Hello everyone currently I am having a problem when working with STM32f103c8t6. Though the circuit can work well with the temperature and moisture measurement, there exists problems in the work of velocity of BLDC fan. As my BLDC fan they can catch up when to stop by the code (when smaller than min_temp or larger than max_temp), but the speed of the fan seems like unchanged to the temperature though I have tried various method by changing from temperature dependence to set up by current, but the fan still seems to run on the same speed. Can anyone help me to address with this problem ? In here I use CubeMx and KeilC version 5 for the coding process
[image: Circuit diagram] [image: Coding for velocity change]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to split your problem into smaller parts:

1. Display the duty_cycle variable on your LCD and check that your computation and measurement is correct. Don't try to debug the PWM if your setpoint is not computed correctly
2. Check that your timer is setup correctly. Change your code to output a constant duty_cycle and check that indeed the output pin outputs that PWM.

Check one thing at a time.

Given the information we have, it's very diffictult to know what is the issue.
You could provide a schematics (not a wiring diagram that is very inconvenient to decipher).
And the complete code of the main.c file, including the timer initialization code generated by cubeMX.